# Google App Script Array, Variables and Pivot table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

Is it possible to use a pivot table referring to a variable where data (arrays) are stored?
Or do the arrays need to be uploaded to a sheet and set a range for them and then use a pivot table ?

Hello everyone, faced with the following task, if it is doable of course :)

In google apps script created a variable that stores an array of data in the format:

Example:

```
[
    [name_1, date_1, age_1],
    [name_2, date_1, age_2],
    [name_3, date_2 ,age_3],
    [name_4, date_3, age_4],
]
```

the data is stored in a variable, type list. I can use indexes to access any element in the array.

There is a lot of data, google sheets will not upload everything to 1 sheet for data aggregation.

Question: is it possible through a variable (without uploading data to a sheet) group by date and count the number of customers?
Is it possible to create a pivot table using variables rather than sheets?

I'm a beginner, maybe the question is stupid :)
Anyway, thank you very much for your answers!`

Comment: It is possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Finding names that share the same date**

```
function myFunk() {
  let arr = [["name_1", "date_1", "age_1"], ["name_2", "date_1", "age_2"], ["name_3", "date_2", "age_3"], ["name_4", "date_3", "age_4"]];
  let obj = arr.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
      a[r[1]] = [{ name: r[0], age: r[2] }]
      a.pA.push(r[1]);
    } else {
      a[r[1]].push({ name: r[0], age: r[2] })
    }
    return a;
  }, { pA: [] })
  obj.pA.forEach(p => {
    if (obj[p].length > 1) {
      Logger.log("The Following names share the same date: %s", obj[p].map(ob => ob.name).join(','));
    }
  })
}

Execution log
4:01:55 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:01:56 PM  Info    The Following names share the same date: name_1,name_2
4:01:57 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

You could have done the same thing with ages as well.